# Does $f''(0)$ exist if $f$ is a real-valued differentiable function on $(−1,1)$ where $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ has a finite limit as $x\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a real-valued differentiable function on $(−1,1)$ such that $\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}$ has a finite limit as $x\rightarrow0$. Does it follow that $f''(0)$ exists? Give a proof or a counterexample.

I have thought of the function $f(x)=x|x|$. Is it fine?

Comment: Does $\frac{x|x|}{x^2}$ have a finite limit as $x\to 0$?

Comment: yes. The limit will be +1 if $x\rightarrow0+$ and $-1$ if $x\rightarrow0-$. Is not it?

Comment: But that's not what "a finite limit" means. You can't have two limits at the same time.

Comment: ok. Then how we can prove it

Comment: Ok. If we choose $f(x)=x^{3}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$, will it work as a counterexample?

Comment: yes that is a counterexample

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:

$$ f(x) = 
  \begin{cases} 
   x^{3}\sin{\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
   0      & \text{if } x = 0
  \end{cases}$$
 Here $$f'(x)=3x^{2}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}-x\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$$ Therefore from the definition of derivative, it follows that $f'(0)=0$. Now it is easy to see that $f''(0)$ do not exist.